Increase the number of recent items on macOS past 50
I want more recent items, because I like having the list.

Most of the results I've found are pre-macOS 11, referencing defaults keys like NSRecentDocumentsLimit and NSNaveRecentPlacesLimit. I haven't found any mentions of these in ~/Library, on macOS 14.5.
Here's a more recent explanation of sharedfilelistd and sfltool, though it's still from Oct 2017: https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/10/recent-items-launch-services-and-sharedfilelists/

I think the options I want would be in ~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist, stored under per-application com.apple.LSSharedFileList.MaxAmount keys. But where is the original value set, other than in System Settings.app?

For now, it appears that this works with Preview.app if I:


cd ~/Library/Application Support/com.apple.sharedfilelist

plutil -convert xml1 com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentDocuments.sfl3
vi com.apple.LSSharedFileList.RecentDocuments.sfl3


modify the integer under com.apple.LSSharedFileList.MaxAmount, from 50 => 250
restart my machine (logging out didn't seem to work)

